# Populating C# ListView With Mysql Table

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

I don't understand why the listview is empty.

[image]

[image]

Refresh button = Button2, and this is my code :

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from Teams", _dbConnect.getConnection());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["team_id"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["team_name"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step through your code and see what's going on. Are you sure your table has data to return?

Comment: I added a photo with my Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add at least one column to your `ListView`. Add another column to display a sub-item.

[image]

Comment: See improved answer. :)

Comment: It works, but how can i dynamicaly add headers for how many columns are in my db Table?

Comment: `foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) { listView1.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName); }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you require subitems in this case, add the items directly;

```
listView1.Items.Add(dr["team_name"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Download and add reference to Mysql.Data dll file

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

```
 public static void fillmyList(ListView myListView, string query)
    {
        myListView.Items.Clear();
        myListView.Columns.Clear();
        string server = "localhost";
        string database = "mydatabaseName";
        string uid = "myUser";
        string password = "MyPassword";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            //Open connection
            if (OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //Read the data and store them in the listview
                if (dataReader.FieldCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            myListView.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(0), 0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myListView.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(i).ToString().Replace("_", " "), 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                    }

                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                    //
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        lv = myListView.Items.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(0)].ToString().Replace('_', ' '));
                        for (int h = 1; h < dataReader.FieldCount; h++)
                        {

                                lv.SubItems.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(h)].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < myListView.Columns.Count; i++)
                    myListView.Columns[i].Width = -2;
                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();
                //close Connection
                CloseConnection();
                         }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

      //open connection to database
    private static bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Close connection
    private static bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can then call the fillmyList method as---  fillmyList (Llistview name,"select * from tablename ");